# Convexity/Closedness of Sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

I want to test the following set against different boundary conditions to determine if it is closed convex:
$$X = \{x \in \mathbb{R^2}:  x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1 \}$$
$$X = \{x \in \mathbb{R^2}:  x_1^2 + x_2^2  < 1 \}$$
$$X = \{x \in \mathbb{R^2}:  x_1^2 + x_2^2  \leq 1 \}$$
$$X = \{x \in \mathbb{R^2}:  x_1^2 + x_2^2  \geq 1 \}$$

*definition*: A set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex if, for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$ and all $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, the point $\lambda x_2 + (1 −\lambda)x_1 \in X$.

*definition*: Closed convex sets are convex sets that contain all their limit points.

**Attempt**:

$X = \{x \in \mathbb{R^2}:  x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1 \}$ is the equation of a circle, which is not convex as the 'interior' is not included

$X = \{x \in \mathbb{R^2}:  x_1^2 + x_2^2  < 1 \}$ Is this still closed? I'm basing my understanding of a limit point from [what is a limit point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663764/what-is-a-limit-point). If so, it should be convex since it includes the interior of the circle, correct?

$X = \{x \in \mathbb{R^2}:  x_1^2 + x_2^2  \leq 1 \}$ similar argument to the previous case, except this includes the boundary (limit point?)

$X = \{x \in \mathbb{R^2}:  x_1^2 + x_2^2  \geq 1 \}$ this set has a hole in it when $r<1$ so it shouldn't be convex

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "open circle" in example 2 does not contain all its limits, you can create a sequence of points in the interior of the disc that approaches the boundary circle.

Example:
$a_n=(0,1-\frac 1 n)$.   These points are clearly all in your set but the limit point $(0,1)$ is not, so it is not closed.

The first, third, and fourth are closed,  but the first and fourth fail to be convex for the reasons you've identified,  the straight line paths between two points are not contained in the space